# view.getMeasuredHeight() return incorrect result when running delayed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I using [ExplandableLayout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) and need to load control inside it dynamically using `addView()` command.

When I adding control inside expandableLayout I need to expand it. But due to the fact that control not really drawn on view when I adding it I need to measure it myself, calling `view.measure` method. And after those call when I invoking `view.getMeasuredHeight()` it's return me correct value. However, if I run the `view.getMeasuredHeight()` in small delay, it's again return me `0` which is wrong. And because of that my expandeblelayout not expanded to proper size.

Small example:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                this.dateTimePickerContainer.setExpanded(true);
                System.out.println(this.getMeasuredHeight()); // log 0
                this.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                System.out.println(this.getMeasuredHeight()); // log 500+ which is correcr value
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    System.out.println(this.getMeasuredHeight()); //log 0 again, why?
    }, 100);}, 
    5000);
```

How could I find what's actually happen with view after those second dalay and why it's goes 0 again?

*I actually waste pretty much time on that, and currently goes out of ideas. So will be appriciate even for any debug tips. Maybe there is a way to monitor, who interacting with view somehow and log this interaction?*